# Stringbuilder() error when passing {}

Tags: .net, escaping, stringbuilder

I am getting a strange error when parsing some javascript into a stringbuilder.

the javascript line that is causing the crash is

```
hbspt.cta.load(789887, 'e977070b-2d40-4d40-bdb4-3459d2ed4d45', {});
```

This line though works perfectly.

```
hbspt.cta.load(789887, 'e977070b-2d40-4d40-bdb4-3459d2ed4d45', );
```

So I assume that the error is with parsing the empty {} the error is `{"Input string was not in a correct format."}`

How should I be dealing with the {} in the string?

Comment: How do you _parse_ a javascript into a stringbuilder?

Comment: the script is in the DB as a string field and is just added via the sb.Append(string);

Comment: Perhaps if you add the code that adds this text to the database your question will be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are calling

```
System.Text.StringBuilder.Append()
```

and it is not

```
System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat()?
```

If you pass "{}" to AppendFormat(), it will interpret the "{0}" as a place holder to substitute value in, and it see "{}" so this is a invalid format string.

In any case, if you have an exception call stack, we can look at the problem better.

Comment: Yep I was doing exactly that... rookie mistake thanks. :)